# Selects filter on js

Tags: javascript, select, filter

I'm learning js, and now I have the task to filter an array of some kinds of point. At the start I have 4 selects with some options, and map, where rendered 10 pins. Each pin it's like a point on map, where somebody get in rent his flat, house, or something else. Selects must filtered this pins, by four parameters: type, costs, rooms, and residents. I programmed selects filtering pins, but they are doing it everyone for themselfs. I need to multiple filtering, but when I use two(or more) selects, pins filtering only by last used select.

And live battlefield, where I'm doing it. 
http://demo.tlpunity.beget.tech/academy/book/

Here is the code.

```
var secondRender = function(arr) {
    mapPins.innerHTML = '';
    articleList.innerHTML = '';
    render(arr);
};

var allElRender = function(arr) {
    mapPins.innerHTML = '';
    articleList.innerHTML = '';
    render(arr);
};

var allPinsArr = [];
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.map__filter');
for(var i = 0;i < selects.length; i++) {

    selects[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selectId = this.id;

        if( selectId === 'housing-type'){
            var typeValue = document.getElementById('housing-type').value; 
            var typeOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('map__filter')[0].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for(var i=0; i<typeOptions.length; i++){

                if(typeValue == near[i].offer.type) {
                    allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.type == typeValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);

                }
                else if(typeValue == 'any'){
                    allElRender(near);
                }
            }
        }
        else if( selectId === 'housing-price') {
            var priceValue = document.getElementById('housing-price').value; 
            var priceOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('map__filter')[1].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for(var i=0; i<priceOptions.length; i++){
                if(priceValue == 'low') {
                    allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.price < 10000;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(priceValue == 'middle'){
                    var allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.price >= 10000 && item.offer.price <= 50000;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(priceValue == 'high'){
                    var allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.price > 50000;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(priceValue == 'any'){
                    allElRender(near);
                }
            }
        }
        else if( selectId === 'housing-rooms') {
            var roomsValue = document.getElementById('housing-rooms').value; 
            var roomsOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('map__filter')[2].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for(var i=0; i<roomsOptions.length; i++){
                if(roomsValue == '1') {
                    allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.rooms == roomsValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(roomsValue == '2'){
                    var allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.rooms == roomsValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(roomsValue == '3'){
                    var allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.price == roomsValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(roomsValue == 'any'){
                    allElRender(near);
                }
            }
        }
        else if( selectId === 'housing-guests') {
            var guestsValue = document.getElementById('housing-guests').value; 
            var guestsOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('map__filter')[3].getElementsByTagName('option');
            for(var i=0; i<guestsOptions.length; i++){
                if(guestsValue == '1') {
                    allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.guests == guestsValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(guestsValue == '2'){
                    var allPinsArr = near.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.offer.guests == guestsValue;
                    });
                    secondRender(allPinsArr);
                }
                else if(guestsValue == 'any'){
                    allElRender(near);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thats not all code, but only filter. If need some information tell me please.
Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var secondRender = function(arr) {
    mapPins.innerHTML = '';
    articleList.innerHTML = '';
    render(arr);
};

var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.map__filter');

var filterData = function() {
  const housingType = document.getElementById('housing-type').value;
  const priceType = document.getElementById('housing-price').value;
  const roomsType = document.getElementById('housing-rooms').value;
  const guestsType = document.getElementById('housing-guests').value;

  return window.near.filter(function(item) {
    var housingTypeIsOk = true;
    var priceTypeIsOk = true;
    var roomsTypeIsOk = true;
    var guestsTypeIsOk = true;

    if (housingType != 'any' && item.offer.type != housingType){
      housingTypeIsOk = false;
    }

    if (priceType != 'any'){
      if (priceType == 'low' && item.offer.price >= 10000) {
        priceTypeIsOk =  false;
      } else if(priceType == 'middle' && (item.offer.price < 10000 || item.offer.price > 50000)){
        priceTypeIsOk = false;
      } else if(priceType == 'high' && item.offer.price <= 50000){
        priceTypeIsOk = false;
      }
    }

    if(roomsType != 'any' && item.offer.rooms != roomsType) {
      roomsTypeIsOk = false;
    } 

    if(guestsType != 'any' && item.offer.rooms != guestsType) {
      guestsTypeIsOk = false;
    }

    return housingTypeIsOk && priceTypeIsOk && roomsTypeIsOk && guestsTypeIsOk;
  });
}

for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  selects[i].onchange = function(e) {
    const filteredData = filterData()
    secondRender(filteredData);
  }
}
```

So after couple unsuccessful attempt to solve this task, I ask my friend help me. And he did it. Idea was that we need to check all selects if one of them was changed. Hope this will help somebody. Keep moving guys!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make one global variable, that contains selected pins. Each time, you use any selector, you should get all pins and filter it by all 4 categories.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply Daria. I tried to do this but I don't realize it. As you can see, I create an arr allPinsArr, just after allElRender function declaration at the top. Then on each select change I'm adding to this arr filtered elements, and I thought that I can use the same arr after first select change, in another select change. But I'm wrong. The filtered pins don't saving in arr. For example if I tried to console.log allPinsArr after declaration selectId, at the begining. I'm getting undefined. I think I have some problems with scope knowledge. Trying to figure it out now:)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you check each select input if it has changed.
You can try to make functions for each select. 
Instead of this: `if( selectId === 'housing-type'){...}` you can filter all pins which will look like this:

```
selects[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    allPinsArr=[...near];//or near.clone()

    //functions to filter pins
    filterFunction1(allPinsArr);
    filterFunction2(allPinsArr);
    filterFunction3(allPinsArr);
    filterFunction4(allPinsArr);
}
```

If select input is selected it should filter. Otherwise don't reduce elements.

This code is my concept based on experience. This code won't work. It is just to show what you can do. Hope, it will help

Comment: thank you Daria. I also tryied this way to solve my problem. but it wasn't successfull, as you can see:) I just step over this task, and moving on course, hope to back this task a little bit later. thank you. Спасибо:)